# Как правильно сделать запрос в БД

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть две таблицы:
Products(содержит поля о товаре)
Images (содержит ссылки на изображения товаров с привязкой по id товара).
Как правильно составить строку запроса чтобы получить к каждому товару только одну ссылку, если это возможно? И можно ли сделать тоже, только отфильтровал по одному из полей товаров?

Answer (score 0):

Задача не совсем понятна, но возможно так:

```
SELECT p.*,i.*
FROM Products AS p
JOIN Images as i on i.product_id=p.id
WHERE p.поле_товара=значение
GROUP BY p.id
```